# AVAudioPlayer quiet when changing songs on speaker

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer, avaudiosession

I have an `AVAudioPlayer` playing a song through the speaker. I made the audio play through the speaker like this.

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] overrideOutputAudioPort:AVAudioSessionPortOverrideSpeaker error:nil];
```

Now I have an `AVAudioPlayer` which I set up like this.

```
player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:currentSong.songLocation error:nil];
```

and I play it like this

```
[player prepareToPlay];
[player play];
```

Everything is fine until I change the audio player like this, where I first update `currentSong` to a new object and init from that

```
player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:currentSong.songLocation error:nil];
[player setVolume:1.0f];
[player prepareToPlay];
[player play];
```

Now the output is quiet, still on the speaker but quiet. If I change the audio output back to `AVAudioSessionPortOverrideNone` and the back to `AVAudioSessionPortOverrideSpeaker`, the sound is loud again, but switching the `AVAudioPlayer` sends me back to "quiet".